# When sending a letter using nodemailer, it gives an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer to send mail from a contact form via SMTP. When sending mail, it gives an error

[image]

How to fix this and set up sending a file with a letter?

Processing a post request on the server:

```js
const express = require('express')
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}))
app.use(express.json())

app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  name = req.body.name,
  telephone = req.body.telephone,
  url = req.headers.referer,
  file = req.body.image
  sendMail(name, telephone, url, file)
  await res.status(200).json('Сообщение отправлено')
})

module.exports = {
  path: '/server/api/form',
  handler: app  
}

const sendMail = async (name, telephone, url, file) => {
  let transporter = await nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.yandex.ru',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: 'test@test.ru',
      pass: '*****'
    },
  })
  transporter.sendMail({
      from: 'test@test.ru',
      to: 'test@test.ru',
      subject: 'Сообщение с сайта ***** | Вакансии',
      text: 'Имя: ' + name + '. Телефон: ' + telephone + '. Страница: ' + url + '. Название файла: ' + file
  })
}
```

If initialization formData not as "const formData = new FormData()", but as "const formData = {}", with more likely my email dont gets into spam.
Vue methods on submit form:

```js
  methods: {
    handleFileUpdate () {
      this.file = this.$refs.file.files[0]
    },
    onSubmit () {
      if (this.$v.$invalid) {
        this.$v.$touch()
        return null
      }
      const fd = new FormData()
      fd.append('image', this.file)
      fd.append('name', this.name)
      fd.append('telephone', this.telephone)
      this.$axios.post('http://localhost:3000/server/api/form', fd, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      })
      this.successValue = true
    }
  }
```

Upload file on server:

```js
const path = require('path')
const multer = require('multer')
const moment = require('moment')

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, path.resolve(__dirname, '../..', 'static'))
  },
  filename(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, `${moment().format('DDMMYYYY-HHmmss_SSS')}-${file.originalname}`)
  }
})
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype === 'image/png' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpg') {
    cb(null, true)
  } else {
    cb(null, false)
  }
}

module.exports = multer({
    storage, fileFilter, limits: {fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5}
})
```

Comment: The error is pretty straight forward, the account, domain or IP you are sending from has been listed in an RBL and rejected as spam.

Comment: Hm, but my letters were sent before I started attaching a document and also transferring data not as a simple object, but through DataForm